# this function is not holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f$ be a complex function defined as
$$f(x+iy)=\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+i\frac{y}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Is this $f$ holomorphic?

my first thought is to use Cauchy-Riemann equations, but I am not sure how to use them. Also, I have the feeling that this function is not holomorphic.

Comment: Take the derivatives demanded by Cauchy-Riemann and show that they are not equal. Intuitively, (but not the way you should prove this in an introductory complex analysis course) this function is $$f(z) = \frac{z}{1+|z|}$$ which depends on $\bar{z}$ i.e. $$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}\right)_z \neq 0$$ The equation $\partial_{\bar{z}}f = 0$ is another form of the Cauchy-Riemann equations. In short, holomorphic functions should not depend on $\bar{z}$ (but independence of $\bar{z}$ is not enough to guarantee analyticity, especially when it comes to functions with singularities).

Comment: @NinadMunshi I need to brush up on complex analysis. By your logic, the function $f(z) = z|z|^2$ shouldn't be holomorphic as $|z|^2 = z\bar{z}$? Could you give a sequence of points converging to $0$, for which $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ doesn't converge, so as to show $f(z)$ isn't holomorphic at $0$? I am unable to find such a sequence.

Comment: @Kaind what is $\partial_{\bar{z}}(z|z|^2)$ at $0$ ? You will see where your counterexample fails to be a counterexample to the point being made.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the 'Writinger derivative'.

Comment: @Kaind ...but you called it by name? A name that I don't even know haha. It's simple, treat $z$ as a constant. Therefore $\partial_{\bar{z}}(z|z|^2) = z^2$

Comment: Yeah no.. that term is mentioned in the only answer to this question. Ok I see, but could you tell me which point $f$ would not be holomorphic , and if possible provide a sequence which shows that the limit of $f(z)/z$ doesn't exist there - just for my understanding.

Comment: @Kaind I think you are misunderstanding something - the limit will exist, why wouldn't it otherwise?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I thought $f$ wasn't holomorphic at $0$ (in which case f(z)/z doesn't have a limit). If it is holomorphic at $0$, my question was at which point was it not holomorphic, and could you prove it for that point (atleast give a starting hint)?

Answer (score 1):

$f(z)=\frac z {1+|z|}$. We can prove that this is not analytic by contradcition. If it is analytic then $\frac {1+|z|} z$ would be analytic at all points except $0$. But the $|z|$  would be analytic at all points except $0$. Can you show that this is not the case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find this is easier if you write $f$ as a function of $z$ and use the Cauchy Riemann equations in the form $\partial_{\overline z}f(z)=0$, where $\partial_{\overline z}$ is the Wirtinger derivative.

Write it as $$f(z)=\frac z{1+|z|}\tag1$$ and use the Wirtinger derivative $\partial_{\overline{z}}$.  Since $|z|=(z\overline{z})^{1/2}$, we have $$\partial_{\overline{z}}|z|=\frac12(z\overline{z})^{-1/2}z=\frac 
 z{2|z|}$$ and $$\partial_{\overline{z}}f(z)=\frac{\left(1+|z|\right)\cdot0-z^2}{2|z|(1+|z|)^2}\neq0$$ so that the function is holomorphic.

Alternatively, if you haven't learned about Wirtinger derivatives, you can argue that if $(1)$ were holomorphic then $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ would be holomorphic in $z\neq0.$  But a holomorphic function taking only real values is constant, contradiction.

Comment: The denominator is only $1+|z|$, not the square root.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Right.  I felt like I was doing something wrong.  Too late at night.